# How to extract, modify single element from set and provide to function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, shutil

How to extract element from set/list and provide to shutil.ignore_patterns directly at once?

Dummy code:

```
import shutil

patterns = set(
    [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]
)
def exclusion_policy():
    return shutil.ignore_patterns('*' + x + '*' for x in (*patterns))
```

Another option is - this works:

```
def exclusion_policy():
    return shutil.ignore_patterns('*A*', '*B*', '*C*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
import shutil

patterns = set(["A", "B", "C"])


def exclusion_policy():
    return shutil.ignore_patterns(*('*' + x + '*' for x in patterns))
```

The `*` unpacks the sequence/collection into positional arguments, in this case the sequence is `('*' + x + '*' for x in patterns)`.